# What am I missing about this Boolean expression expansion?

Tags: boolean-algebra

Sorry if this is too basic, but I am working through [Boolean Algebra and Its Applications](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486477673) and do not understand this expansion in the author's example 5 in section 1-6:

$$(A+X+Y)(A+B'+Y') \rightarrow (A+AX+B'X+XY'+AY+B'Y)$$

But where are $AB'$ and $AY'$?

Comment: $BY$ does not come due to expansion...

Comment: Good catch. I fixed that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have this book, but I have some limited knowledge about boolean algebra. I believe this should help: $$A+AB'+AY'= A+AY',$$ by the absorption rule. Use it again to get: $$A+AY'=A.$$

Comment: Right! I'm not sure why he's not using the Law of Absorption on $AY$, but perhaps that becomes useful later in the simplification.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have that textbook, but notice that:
\begin{align*}
(A+X+Y)(A+B'+Y')
&= A + (X+Y)(B'+Y') \\
&= A + (B'X + B'Y + XY' + YY') \\
&= A + B'X + B'Y + XY' \\
\end{align*}